# How to limit the RAM used by multiple embedded HSLQDB DB instances as a whole?

Tags: hsqldb

Given:

1. HSQLDB embedded
2. 50 distinct databases (I have 50 different data sources)
3. All the databases are of the `file:/` kind
4. All the tables are CACHED
5. The amount of RAM allowed to use by all the embedded DB instances combined is limited and given upon startup of the java process.
6. The LOG file is disabled (no need to recover upon crash)

My understanding is that the RAM used by a single DB instance is comprised of the following pieces:

- The cache of all the tables (all my tables are CACHED)
- The DB instance internal state

Also, as far as I can see I have these two properties to control the total size of the cache of a single DB instance:

- SET FILES CACHE SIZE
- SET FILES CACHE ROWS

However, they control only the cache part of the RAM used by a DB instance. Plus, they are per DB instance, whereas I would like to limit all the instances as a whole.

So, I wonder whether it is possible to instruct HSQLDB to stay within the specified amount of RAM in total including all the DB instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only limit the CACHE memory use per database instance. Each instance is independent of the other.

You can reduce the CACHE SIZE and CACHE ROWS per database to suit your application.

HSQLDB does not use a lot of other memroy, but when it does, it uses the memory of the JVM, which is shared among the different database instanced.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to calculate the amount of RAM used by the hsqldb? TaskMgr is of no help to me, since it reports the RAM occupied by the java process, of which the hsqldb is only a part.

Comment: No. Because it's all in the same Java process.